# What screwdriver do I need for this 'star' shaped fitting?

Tags: screws

I need to unscrew the screw in this picture. It doesn't seem to be using a standard fitting however. What screwdriver so I need for this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a **Torx bit** also sometimes referred to as **star drive**.

You may be able to get a fixed screwdriver with the right size one but it's generally a better deal to just get a bit assortment and mount an adequately sized one on some sort of a socketed shaft, depending on the application.

[image]

Note: Torx drive invented originally by Camcar Textron to eliminate the rounding issue standard hex drive bits suffer.